# I want to know more about how a particular exploit works. How do I do that?

Tags: disassembly, linux, exploit, buffer-overflow

I am given a VM of a server running a [vulnerable version of ProFTP](https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/linux/ftp/proftp_telnet_iac) and a attacker VM which exploits the server using [an exploit provided with MetaSploit](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/modules/exploits/linux/ftp/proftp_telnet_iac.rb). I need to write a Snort rule to detect potential malicious attacks on the server as a part of my class assignment. Looking at the exploit code I can easily write a rule to look for the keyword `SITE` or `\x8d\xa0\xfc\xdf\xff\xff` (as my vulnerable Vm is an Ubuntu machine). However, that would be pretty lame and also writing patches specific to the code of the exploit is not a good practice. I would like the rule to apply even if the exploit code is changed.

I have read about [the bug](http://bugs.proftpd.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3521) and I know that the presence of special IAC character (255 or `\xFF`) would potentially lead to buffer overflow. However, any normal packet could contain  `\xFF` and writing a rule for detecting `\xFF` would to false positives. I want to know some specific details of the exploit which would either help me figure out where I need to look for the IAC character or help me find some details about the exploit which would allow me to find malicious packets without having to resort to look for IAC character `\xFF`. How do I go about doing that? Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Currently, I have installed [udcli](http://udis86.sourceforge.net/) to try to understand the commands in the `ROPStack` portion of the code. For ex: I am trying to evaluate line 100 (`0x805a544,  # mov eax,esi / pop ebx / pop esi / pop ebp / ret`) in the code. I have tried:

```
echo "08 05 a5 44" | udcli -32 -x
echo "805a544" | udcli -32 -x
echo "44 a5 05 08" | udcli -32 -x
echo "44 a5 05 80" | udcli -32 -x
```

But none of them evaluates to the following sequence

```
mov eax,esi
pop ebx
pop esi
pop ebp
ret
```

Comment: ProFTPD is open-source and the vulnerability is very well-documented, meaning there's no need to analyze a specific exploit. Your question would be better asked on http://security.stackexchange.com/ as writing a Snort rule does not require any reverse engineering in this context.

Comment: He clearly stated that he is studying this vulnerability as part of a class, with the intent to learn. Although his question is a bit vague, completely disregarding it because others have analyzed the exploit, is contrary to the point of stack exchange.

Comment: @jbh: Asking a question unrelated to reverse engineering is contrary to the point of the Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange :)

Comment: I'd argue reverse engineering an exploit, is completely related to Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange ;)

Comment: I am not very sure if I want to know how to write a Snort rule. I have written a couple of them and I think I can write Snort rules. I want to know what causes the vulnerability. For ex: In the code there is a part which says `becomes eax (GOT of mmap64)` (its in comments). Honestly, I am unable to understand how does that hex (i.e. `0x80db330`) map to GOP of mmap64 and I want to know such things. If there would be another exploit would it necessarily give GOP of `mmap`? Or there could be other possible ways? This is what I am looking for. Does this help?

Comment: @TheRookierLearner: from what I see in the bug link you provided, integer underflow is triggered by `buf[4102] == TELNET_IAC`

Comment: Thanks! I guess checking for IAC character when any FTP user sends a command would help me.

Comment: Just reminder: don't forget to check for abscence of `\n` in the first 4102 bytes

Comment: I didn't quite get you. Why would that matter? Wouldn't a `TELNET_IAC` character be sufficient?

Comment: `'\n'` means the end of src-buffer for the `pr_netio_telnet_gets` function. If your snort rule somehow a-priori knows the length of buffer you can skip this test by efficiency consideration, ofc